# Visualize Apache Camel route without XML

Tags: apache-camel

Is it possible to visualize Apache Camel route without XML?

XML visualization is possible with (Red Hat plugin for) Eclipse.

What about Java/Kotlin DSL?

They seem to have all required information in single file (like XML).

Comment: [hawt.io](http://hawt.io/plugins/camel/) can visualize a route from a running camel context (not design time/or not from the IDE).

Comment: @mgyongyosi it can only visualise xml